# Infinite Computation of two functions

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have the following two functions

```
let rec f n =
    if n < 10 then "f" + g (n + 1) else "f"
and g n =
    if n < 10 then "g" + f (n + 1) else "g"
```

Where I need to find out if there are any argument to f that can start an infinite computation.

My immediate answer would be no, as there is an upper bound of 10, that always will return a letter. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm assuming lines 2 and 4 are supposed to be indented, otherwise this isn't valid F#.*

## In Theory

`g` and `f` are identical except for output, and we don't care for output. So we might as well look at the following function, which has the same termination properties but drops the output:

```
let rec f n = if n < 10 then f (n + 1)
```

The input type to `f` is `int`, which is a 32 bit signed integer. It only allows values from -2147483648 to 2147483647 (`System.Int32.MinValue` and `System.Int32.MaxValue`). There are no other representable cases.

Well, that thing terminates for any input of 10 or higher, and otherwise just counts up until it reaches 10 and then terminates.

## In Practice

That said, the way the functions in the question concatenate strings has O(n²) time-complexity. I don't think you want to wait for a call like `f System.Int32.MinValue` to terminate on a real computer. Also, these are not tail recursive. You'll blow your stack or your time constraints for sure. So this is a case of looking at theoretical properties that are useless in reality.

*In other words: um, what are you even doing?*

Comment: *In other words: um, what are you even doing?* My guess would be "a homework assignment". :-)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Yes, it's a homework assignment. Just wanted to make sure my answer was correct.